# How to create a google contact in "All Contacts" group using google contacts API v3?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

When creating a google contact using the google contacts API v3, is there any way to specify/set the group membership for the contact to be created to "All Contacts" without actually knowing the id/href for the "All Contacts" group?

When I say "All Contacts" group, I'm referring to the default contacts group in the new google contacts UI. I think this was called "My Contacts" in the older google contacts UI.

I'm using the REST API directly and I would like to avoid making an additional REST call to get the available groups information before making the actual REST call to create the contact. Pre-fetching/caching the groups information in memory is not a feasible option since the google account for which the contact is being created is not constant, and the number of accounts this code handles is very large.

The id/href for the "All Contacts" group seems to be of the form 
"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{user-email}/base/6". Is is safe to assume this will not change without notice?

Comment: As far as I know, without group id you cannot assign contact to a group even if its default. You can default only for userid not for the group. To assign contact to a group, you should know the group id.